# WCF services reference copy

Tags: .net, wcf, service, reference

I inherited an old website maintenance after a guy left the office, the website is currently working without trouble and I've only had to do a few little changes.

But as we're planning a major update I wanted to upgrade the project from visual 2005 to at least vs 2008. The conversion worked fine except for the WCF service for which I cannot get the the service reference of even just update but the service can still be called.

I don't have a lot of experience with WCF, I just know it's an external service we don't have access to.

What do you think I can do ?

Comment: What do you mean by don't have access to? You say you can call it.

Comment: I meant I cannot make any modification what so ever in the server

Comment: I get the error "There was no end point listening at ..." but I just checked again to be sure, the service is running because I get a response to my request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad

it looks it was configured with an old url in the class library (maybe I should have mention that:-|) but in the web application project it had the new url in the web.config.

My bad, my fail